# Do I need to force the use of TLS 1.2 in my ASP .NET 4.6 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tls1.2, .net-4.6

We have a third party API that will shortly be enforcing the use of TLS 1.2.

We have two separate applications that connect to this API, a console application and an ASP.NET web application, both written in C#.

I have re-targeted the console application to use .NET 4.6 which is also installed onto the host machine. I have added this at the top of `Main`.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Enable TLS 1.2
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

   // Disable old protocols
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~(SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11);

    ...

}
```

I'm confident that this is enough for the console application as it only has this one entry point.

However I'm confused about what I need to do for the ASP.NET web application.

Firstly it's made up of 3 projects. Two are class libraries for the framework and service layer respectively, the third is the ASP web application for the UI. I've gone through each one of these and targeted them for .NET 4.6.
From what I've read this sounds like all I need to do as the highest protocol will be negotiated by default.

Am I correct?

If I'm wrong, where do I add the same line from the console app? Global.asax?

Comment: is it hosted in IIS?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, IIS 8.5.

Comment: that's where you'll configure it.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not making people use TLS 1.2 to connect to my site, I want to tell my app to use TLS 1.2 when speaking to the third party API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is a `static`, you only have to configure it once per application. That would mean it is enough to put that code in the `Application_Start` event.